# Why the following javascript function (drawBorder()) is not cutting a hole?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a border by cutting a rectangular hole inside a rectangle. The rectangle is showing up the way it is supposed to but can't figure out why the hole is not showing up.

```js
var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
var aspRat;
var viewLength;

init();
draw();
renderScene();

function init(){
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
    
    canvasWidth = window.innerWidth - 50;
    console.log(canvasWidth);
    canvasHeight = window.innerHeight - 50;
    console.log(canvasHeight);
    
    renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    document.getElementById("WebGLCanvas").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    viewLength = 1000;
    aspRat = canvasWidth/canvasHeight;
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-aspRat*viewLength/2, aspRat*viewLength/2,
                                          viewLength/2, -viewLength/2, -1000, 1000);
    console.log(aspRat*viewLength);
    console.log(aspRat);
    console.log(viewLength);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 15);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    
    scene.add(camera);
}


function draw(){
    
    drawBorder();
    
}

function renderScene(){
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
}


function drawBorder() {
    
    
    var border = new THREE.Shape();
    
    border.moveTo(-aspRat*viewLength/2, viewLength/2);
    border.lineTo(aspRat*viewLength/2, viewLength/2);
    border.lineTo(aspRat*viewLength/2, -viewLength/2);
    border.lineTo(-aspRat*viewLength/2, -viewLength/2);
    border.lineTo(-aspRat*viewLength/2, viewLength/2);
    
    
    
    var rectHole = new THREE.Path();
    
    rectHole.moveTo(-aspRat*viewLength/2 - 15, viewLength/2 - 10);
    rectHole.lineTo(aspRat*viewLength/2 - 15, viewLength/2 - 10);
    rectHole.lineTo(aspRat*viewLength/2 - 15, -viewLength/2 - 10);
    rectHole.lineTo(-aspRat*viewLength/2 - 15, -viewLength/2 - 10);
    rectHole.lineTo(-aspRat*viewLength/2 - 15, viewLength/2 - 10);
    border.holes.push(rectHole);
    
    var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( border );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0x663300});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );
    scene.add(mesh);
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r72/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    
    
    <head>
    
        <title>StainedGlass</title>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content= "width=640, height=480, initial-scale=1">
        
        <style type= "text/css">
            
            body{
                    background-color: #000000;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    margin: 0px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
            }
            
            #slider1{
                position: relative;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
            }
            
        </style>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/three.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div id="WebGLCanvas">
            
            
            <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.1"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="src/myScript.js"></script>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: The rectangle for the hole is not inside the big rectangle. Specify the coordinates for the hole in counterclockwise order.

Comment: Specifying the co-ordinates of the main rectangle in counterclockwise and adjusting the vertices did the trick. Thanks for reminding to use counterclockwise way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `THREE.Shape` with a hole, and using a pattern like the following:

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
var hole = new THREE.Path();
...
shape.holes.push( hole );

var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
```

You have to be careful about the order in which you specify the vertices of the shape and the holes.

Try specifying the vertices of the shape in counterclockwise order, and the vertices of the holes in clockwise order.

three.js r.72